# Data structure for a Rete in production rule system

Tags: data-structures, trees

## Example of Data

This is the data for one monkey. There are many similar but different monkeys.

```
X(Y,Z) means Y, Z are parent of X.

A(D,E)  If monkey see banna (D) and monkey is hungry (E), it squeaks (A).
B(E,F)  If monkey is hungry (E), and monkey see other monkey, it jumps(B).
C(D,F)  If monkey see banna (D), and it is not hungry (E), it walks away(C).   
0(A,B)  If monkey squeak(A) and jumps(B), it grabs the banna
        with priority 10 and reduce priority for doing other
        things (0).

D, E, F are the source.
```

*Notice that this is not a tree.* A-C-D is a undirected cycle. Trees have no cycle ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Definition)). The priority and the words at right are not part of the data structure I am interested in (at this moment).

## Question

Is there a data structure that conserves memory and allow reasonably efficient recalculation of values for the following case?

The data structure is for the rete algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm).

[Description of the data]

1. Each node (except the end points) has exactly two parents.
2. Any two parents have at most one child.
3. A node can be the parent of multiple nodes.
4. Each node has value, which is a boolean. (Or an array of fixed number of boolean for sharing the nodes between different monkeys.)
5. Value of child is logical and of values of its parents.
6. Want to keep all values of the nodes to save recalculation time.

[Operations on the data structure]

1. The structure of the graphs never changes. I don't mind taking a long time to construct the data structure.
2. When value of a node changes, values of its children are
   recalculated. The values of the end points occasionally changes in
   every cycles of calculation.
3. Want to know if the predefined
   interesting nodes (for example we know that node 0,3,and 5 are
   interesting.) change value.
4. Don't need to query or look up for any
   particular values among the nodes. Also don't need to output values
   of all the nodes (that would take too much time.)

There are lots of nodes, and lots of parent-child relationships, because there are lots and lots of rules, and lots of slightly different monkeys.

(I have never taken any computer science class... I learned everything online. Sorry if I use the wrong terms.)

Comment: by the way, is there a name for this situation?

Comment: Do you have this common subtree or have to find it? Recalculations are essentialy the same among all shared resources? So if you allocate such subtree separately and add list of parents to the root is it ok?

Comment: The data of each node is either true or false, and is the logical and between data of the two children. The structure of the graph is known in advance.

Comment: @Evil: I finally get what you mean by common subtree. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065538/theoretically-what-data-structure-can-i-use-for-trees-with-shared-memory

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to optimise. Assuming you're trying use as little memory as possible to represent the data (since you said `Is there a data structure that conserves memory for the following case?`), then it's as easy as only storing the data of the so called "end points" since value of all other points can be calculated as needed. OR perhaps you are implicitly wanting something else as well from this data structure, such as, low update time or low query time. In short, try to re-explain what you really want.

Comment: That is, if I understand the question correctly, this situation looks like the "end points" are some boolean variables that can change its value, and the other points are basically logical `and` of the end points. Ignoring the messy way you describe that each other points has exactly two parents. Because, remember that logical `and` is associative and commutative.

Comment: I would want to keep all data in the nodes because those data saves update time, and there are a lot of nodes. this structure is a rete in rule based system. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm).

Comment: If your common subtree (if I am close to your needs) is full binary tree (every node besides leaves has two children) and you want to lower memory footprint and your values are boolean then maybe this part could be an array instead of tree (three pointers are heavy in compare with one boolean), bit array maybe? What is expected depth of that tree (in the worst case)?

Comment: quite deep, it is like the number of variables required to predict how would a group of monkeys help each other to survive. since each monkey more or less follow similar rules, each node can have a bitarray with each bit representing a monkey. The rules that each monkey follows are not exactly identical though.

Comment: What operations are you looking to perform on this data structure, to read values from it?   Is the only thing you want to do is to output all values of all nodes?  Or do you want to be able to look up the value of a node quickly?  Are all queries available in advance, or do you have to handle them in realtime?

Comment: Don't need to output values of all nodes, to look up value of all the nodes, or to search for a value over the nodes.  Just need to know if the values of predefined interesting nodes change (which will change the monkey's priority for some action.) Need to do necessary recalculation of values quickly and conserve memory. The things that each monkey knows can change often.

Comment: What's wrong with storing the tree explicitly?

Comment: @Raphael: 1. How to "store the tree explicitly"? I really don't know... I used sparse matrices and list before but not graphs/tree with high memory efficiency. 2. Most of the time, it is not a tree, see example 2. 3. Rete uses a lot of memory. There are a lot of nodes, because the monkey follows a lot of rules, and not all monkey have the same rules

Comment: dot dot dot, I notice there have been a lot of edits to this post. I don't want to discourage you from making changes to improve your question.  That said, each time it is edited, the question gets "bumped" to the top of the front page and pushes other questions down, so you might want to consider whether it would be possible to space out your edits a little more (e.g., batch them up so that you combine the changes into a single edit).  Also, it looks like many of the comments may no longer be needed.  Can you flag as 'obsolete' all comments that have since been addressed?